# Fixed number of gridlines?

Tags: plotting

I am interested in making multiple plots with the same amount of "GridLines" and "FrameTicks", particularly for plot-range -> all.  Is there a straightforward way to do this and set it as a default option?

Here are some images as an example:
[image]
[image]

And here's some code to reproduce something similar without the dashed lines.

```
SetOptions[Plot, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 30}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
  PlotStyle -> {{ColorData[101, "ColorList"], 
     Thickness[.015]}, {Black, Thickness[.03], Dotted  }, {Black , 
     Thickness[.015]}}];

analyticalSol = (100000000 ((0.` + 600.` I) + 
      1000000 \[CapitalDelta]pMHz) (2.25`*^12 + 
      2 ((0.` - 600.` I) - 
         1000000 \[CapitalDelta]pMHz) (1206000000 I + 
         2 (1163000000 + 
            1000000 \[CapitalDelta]pMHz))) Sqrt[\[Pi] Log[
      2]])/(((1206000000 + 
         2 I (-1163000000 - 
            1000000 \[CapitalDelta]pMHz)) (144000000000000 + 
         2 (600.` - 1000000 I \[CapitalDelta]pMHz) (1206000000 - 
            2000000 I \[CapitalDelta]pMHz)) + 
      2.25`*^12 (1206000000 - 
         2000000 I \[CapitalDelta]pMHz)) (600.` - 
      1000000 I \[CapitalDelta]pMHz))

g11 = Plot[
  Re[ComplexExpand[analyticalSol]], {\[CapitalDelta]pMHz, -10, 10}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, None}}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
  BaseStyle -> 12, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> {300, 300}]
g12 = Plot[
  Im[ComplexExpand[analyticalSol]], {\[CapitalDelta]pMHz, -10, 10}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, None}}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
  BaseStyle -> 12, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{0, .06, .12}, None}, {{-10, 0, 10}, None}}]
```

Comment: You can always do `SetOptions[Plot,.....]` and set in there the common options for all you plots?

Comment: @Nasser, I'm using SetOptions already, as you can see in the code. The issue is that I need to know the plotrange in order to have a specific number of grid lines.

Comment: I meant to fix the actual values in the `SetOptions`. But it seems you want something else. If each plot will have different plot range, not sure how this will work out. sounds hard problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[setPlotOptions]
setPlotOptions[major : (_Integer | _List | Automatic) : 6, minor_: 6] := 
 SetOptions[Plot, {Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 18}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
   Sequence @@ Switch[Head[major], 
     Integer, {FrameTicks -> 
       {{Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][#, #2, {major, minor}] &, Automatic}, 
       {Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][#, #2, {major, minor}] &, Automatic}}, 
        GridLines -> {FindDivisions[{#, #2}, major] &, FindDivisions[{#, #2}, major] &}}, 
     List, {FrameTicks -> major, GridLines -> {major[[2, 1]], major[[1, 1]]}},
      _, {FrameTicks -> Automatic, GridLines -> Automatic}]}]
```

***Examples:***

```
setPlotOptions[];

Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Plot[x Sin[10 x], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
setPlotOptions[20, 1];

Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Plot[x Sin[10 x], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
setPlotOptions[{{Subdivide[-1., 2, 4], Automatic}, {Range[-10, 10], Automatic}}];

Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Plot[x Sin[10 x]/5, {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

You can override any of the options set by `SetOptions` inside `Plot`. For example,

```
Plot[x Sin[10 x]/5, {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 FrameTicks -> Automatic,
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think you could explain some of the syntax? 
I'm not sure I understand "[major : (_Integer | _List | Automatic) : 6, minor_: 6]" I haven't seen something like this before.

Comment: @StevenSagona, the function `setPlotOptions` takes two _optional_ arguments . When provided, the first argument should be an Integer or a  list or `Automatic`. If no argument is provided (the function is called as `setPlotOptions[]`) the two arguments take the _default value 6.  If it is called with a single argument (e.g. `setPlotOptions[10]`) the scond argument takes the default value 6.  See the tutorial [Optional And Default Arguments](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html) in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, perhaps more convenient, approach is to define a wrapper function that propagates the option value for `FrameTicks` to set the option value for `GridLines`.

While we are at it, (1) we can inject additional options in the definition of the wrapper function so that we don't have set them again in `Plot`, and (2) we can trick  `FrameTicks` to "accept" option values that it would normally not accept (such as `FrameTicks -> {10, 5}` to specify (up to) 10 automatically selected major ticks on the horizontal axis and 5 on the vertical axis, or, `FrameTicks -> {{6, 4},{10,5}}` to specify (up to) 6  major and 4 minor ticks on the horizontal axis and 10 major 5 minor ticks on the vertical axis).

We use [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) to define the function `propagateOV` :

```
ClearAll[propagateOV]
propagateOV /: Rule[FrameTicks, propagateOV[a_]] := 
 {ImageSize -> Medium, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
  Rule[FrameTicks, 
   Switch[a, 
     _Integer, {{Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][#, #2, a] &, Automatic}, 
          {Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][#, #2, a] &, Automatic}},
    {_Integer, _Integer}, {{Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][#, #2, Last@a] &, Automatic}, 
          {Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][#, #2, First@a] &, Automatic}},
    {{_Integer, _Integer}, _} | {_, {_Integer, Integer}}, 
        {{Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][#, #2, Last@a] &, Automatic}, 
        {Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][#, #2, First@a] &, Automatic}} ,
    _, a]], 
  Rule[GridLines, 
   Switch[a,
     _Integer, {FindDivisions[{#, #2}, a] &, FindDivisions[{#, #2}, a] &}, 
    {_Integer, _Integer}, 
        {FindDivisions[{#, #2}, First@a] &, FindDivisions[{#, #2}, Last@a]&} , 
    {{_Integer, _Integer}, {_Integer, _Integer}}, 
        {FindDivisions[{#, #2}, a[[1, 1]]] &, FindDivisions[{#, #2}, a[[2, 1]]] &} ,
    {{_List, _}, {_List, _}}, a[[{2,1}, 1]], 
     _, Automatic]]}
```

***Examples:***

Set (up to) 15 (automatically selected) major ticks for both axes (left panel) and (up to) 15 major ticks for horizontal and 5 for the vertical axes (right panel)   and set the `GridLines` accordingly:

```
Row[{Plot[x Sin[10 x], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}, FrameTicks -> propagateOV@15], 
  Plot[x Sin[10 x], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}, FrameTicks -> propagateOV@{15, 5}]}]
```

[image]

Specify different major and minor ticks for horizontal and vertical axes and set the `GridLines` at major ticks:

```
Row[{Plot[x Sin[10 x], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi},  FrameTicks -> propagateOV@{{15, 5}, {5, 5}}], 
  Plot[x Sin[10 x], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}, FrameTicks -> propagateOV@{{15, 1}, {5, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

`Automatic` frame ticks  with (right panel)  and without (left panel) the `propagateOV` wrapper:

```
Row[{Plot[x Sin[10 x], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> Medium, FrameTicks -> Automatic],
  Plot[x Sin[10 x], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}, FrameTicks -> propagateOV@Automatic]}]
```

[image]

User-specified lists of ticks  with (right panel)  and without (left panel) the `propagateOV` wrapper:

```
Row[{Plot[x Sin[10 x], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}, Frame -> True,  ImageSize -> Medium,
    FrameTicks -> {{Range[-10, 10, 2], Automatic}, {Range[-5, 15, 3], Automatic}}], 
  Plot[x Sin[10 x], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}, 
   FrameTicks -> 
     propagateOV@{{Range[-10, 10, 2], Automatic}, {Range[-5, 15, 3], Automatic}}]}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Finally, you can over-ride the options set by `propagateOV` by simply putting the options you want to override before the option `FrameTicks`:

```
Plot[x Sin[10 x], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}, 
 Axes -> True, ImageSize -> Large, GridLinesStyle -> Green,
 FrameTicks -> propagateOV@{15, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `GridLines` specification can be a function. It will be passed the min and max values of the variable in the direction it applies to, and returns gridline positions (and other style specifications, if you want). That gives you access to the plot range from *within the plotting function*.

You can use `Subdivide` with a specified number of gridlines to generate a constant number of gridlines at varying spacing depending on the plot range:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, GridLines -> {(Subdivide[##, 4][[2 ;; -2]] &), None}]
Plot[Sin[x/2], {x, 0, 100}, GridLines -> {(Subdivide[##, 4][[2 ;; -2]] &), None}]
```

[image: small range]
[image: large range]

`Subdivide` will always return the first and last values in the range, but I think you do not want those, looking at your plots; that’s the reason for the `Part` selection.

Another option would be `FindDivisions` but I find that often that function's choice of "nice" division points does not agree with mine.